# Jointly distributed random variable $P(X^2+Y^2) \lt 1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am analyzing the below problem:

**Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with joint pdf**

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4} &  -1 \leq x ; & y \leq 1 \\[6pt]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

**Determine  $\Pr(X^2 + Y^2 < 1)$**

Solution:

$$
\Pr(X^2 + Y^2 < 1)= \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{4} r \, dr  \, d \theta = \frac{\pi}{4}
$$

**My questions:**
I assume that the $X^2 + Y^2$ would represent a circle but cannot grasp how the boundaries for the integrals are determined  (especially where does the $2 \pi$ come from?)  and where the $\frac{1}{4} r$ under the integrals come from. Would anyone help me understand this solution please?

Comment: I changed $f_{xy}(x,y)$ to $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.  The distinction between capital $X$ and lower-case $x$ is there for a reason. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pure geometry. The integral of $\frac{1}{4}$ over the region $x^2+y^2\le 1$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ times the area of a disk (circle) of radius $1$.

We need not even mention the integral. The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is uniform over a certain $2\times 2$ square that contains the disk, so the probability that $X^2+Y^2$ is $\lt 1$ is the area of the unit disk divided by the area of the $2\times 2$ square.

**Remark:** Essentially the solution you quote finds the area of the unit disk by switching to polar coordinates. Definitely the hard way! But $r$ does go from $0$ to $1$, and the angle $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$, once around the circle.

Comment: ok, I see, the equation for area of a circle was used directly. Thanks for the hints.  I tried to derive the answer in the analytical way where I set the integral intervals from 0  and multiplied the integral by 4. I assume this  is correct either.  $P(X^2+Y^2<1) = P(X<\sqrt{1-y^2})=4 \int_{0}^{1}  \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}  \frac{1}{4} \,dx dy = \int_{0}^{1} ([x]_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}) \, dy = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-y^2} \,\, dy = [2arcsin(x)+sin(2arcsin(x))]_{0}^{1} = \frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Sure, you can find the area of the circle using integration in rectangular coordinates. Polar coordinates are easier in this case, and quoting the standard fact about the area of the circle even easier.